# Call SSIS from c# web app and display progress

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS package that loads data from an excel file to a database.

The user goes to the intranet page (normal c# .net 4.0 web app), selects the file they want to upload, and then clicks a button. The button copies the file to the server and then starts a SQL job that calls the package. This works fine and dandy but the user has no idea when the job finishes.

What's the best way to show the user that the package has completed (or failed)?

I have seen links like - http://www.programminghelp.com/database/sqlserver/sql-server-integration-services-calling-ssis-package-in-c/ but this is for C# Console Project. What's the best way to do this with a web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this but if you're looking for an easy way then you could use the [SmtpClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) in the System.Net.Mail namespace to send an email to the user when the job finishes. (There's a nice, simple code snippet on that page that you could reuse readily.) Of course you would have to have a sending account set up (no-reply@myAutomatedJobThing.com for example) and know the user's email address.

Whether this is the best solution in your scenario is debatable but I've seen it employed (and employed it myself) for a number of systems where such a process takes an appreciable amount of time, say a couple of minutes or longer. If your import just takes a few seconds then the email solution might be overkill.

A simpler, AJAX-style solution might involve browsing to a page (after initiation) that polls the job via a timer and displays the progress in-page. Even an auto-reload might work. The piece of metadata you would need for this is a unique identifier for the job that the user executed.

Comment: We've done this in the SSIS package. Send an email on completion or failure. If the package goes through 8 different steps and takes 5 minutes, we want to let the user know that step 1 or step 2 (and so on) has completed. Anyway to display this?

Comment: Yes there is. But you would have to set up an asynch process from the page (think AJAX) to stay on the page and also receive progress updates.

Comment: See my updated answer. You might be able to use an auto-refreshing page. Not sure why I'm assuming you want to not use AJAX, but that is one of your options.

Comment: That seems like that might be the path we take (auto-refresher). Do you have any references off hand? AJAX would be cool but probably more work that we want to put in.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to go but all I have to go on is that you're using C# and it's web app. That's a big world. I would suggest posting another question along those lines and including your specific technologies and versions and of course the intent.